# two different size of dataset filtering via considering timestamp using matlab?

Tags: matlab, timestamp, interpolation

I have two very large dataset of matlab. In both dataset we have different parameter. The only common parameter is timestamp means measuring value of all parameter with every 10 min of interval. Let us take an example,

In dataset 1 , I have  Timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD , HH : MM :SS  format) and power
In dataset 2, I have again timestamp(in above format) and speed

I want a new dataset which have power and speed with timestamp synchronization.  For example :

```
       TimeStamp                         P           S
  2014 - 01 - 01 , 00 :10               100          5
                   00 :20                           7
                   00:30                150         10
                   00:40                200          
                   00:50                145         12
                   01:00                50          7
                   01:10                            6
```

etc............

So in short the output of the final dataset must be like :

```
       TimeStamp                         P           S
        00 :10                          100          5
         00:30                          150         10    
         00:50                          145         12
```

So basically if i am getting both power and speed with same time then it should take otherwise filter rest.

And  If we have different size of observation in both data set will it work ??  Even though they might have different observation size but I want only those data in my final database whose P and S matching with time Stamp and if it is not making then my final data base exclude those sets

anyone help me on this with the help of matlab ???    thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
%type "help ismember" in command window to see what the function does

%finds index of timestamp in dataset1 that exists in dataset 2
indexPinS = ismember(dataset1(:,1),dataset2(:,1));
%finds index of timestamp in dataset2 that exists in dataset 1
indexSinP = ismember(dataset2(:,1),dataset1(:,1));

%combines data in final database
finalDatabase = [dataset1(indexPinS,1), dataset1(indexPinS,2), dataset2(indexSinP,2)];
```

Comment: Is this type of code will give me power and speed as per time synchronization...??

Comment: As long as your vectors are organized as follows

    dataset1 = [timestamp, P];
    dataset2 = [timestamp, S];

Comment: Thank you very much , it is working.... I would be grateful if you explain me what is going on in following programming by using % in each line of code that you have written above :

Comment: use matlab help for more information. Please accept the provided answer if it is working.